# Sending exception message from Step-functions to aws cloudwatch event logs

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-step-functions, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

When AWS Step-function fails, the output message is null and same is passed to cloudwatch event logs, but the error message in exception is not passed to cloudwatch events log. How can I send that exception message to cloudwatch events log so that I can process it downstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using below boto3.client(‘stepfunctions’) and then using get_execution_history() method to retrieve the cause and error.

Answer (score 1):

[CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html) and [CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html) are two different services. If you enable logging at `ERROR`, `FATAL`, or `ALL` log level, you'll see the errors in CloudWatch Logs. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/cw-logs.html

I assume you're referring to CloudWatch Events/EventBridge here. [The events Step Functions emits to CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/cw-events.html) contain the result of the [DescribeExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_DescribeExecution.html) API. It doesn't include errors, just the input and output of the execution. The error and cause that caused the execution to fail is in the `executionFailedEventDetails` field of last event in the execution history. You can retrieve the last event by calling [GetExecutionHistory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_GetExecutionHistory.html) with `"reverseOrder": true` and `"maxResults": 1`.